# What does "Fixed-Point Lemma" says intuitively?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, incompleteness

The lemma as stated in Enderton's logic says:

> **Fixed-Point Lemma**.   Given any formula $\beta$ in which only $v_1$ occurs free, we can find a sentence $\sigma$ such that
>
> $$ A_E \vdash [\sigma \leftrightarrow \beta(\mathbf S^{\sharp\sigma}\mathbf 0)]. $$
>
> We can think of $\sigma$ as indirectly saying, “$\beta$ is true of me.”

I wonder what does "$\beta$ is true of me" mean?

Can the lemma be interpreted as:

For any formula $\beta$ having one free variable $x$, there is a sentence $\sigma$ which we can think of $\beta$ as saying $\sigma$ is true.

Is that what the lemma says ***indirectly***? If not, What is the right interpretation of it then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, we are considering formulae (like $\beta, \sigma$) in *first-order* language of *arithmetic*; thus, their "standard" interpretation are assertions about *numbers*.

We can think of $\beta(v_1)$ with $v_1$ free, as a sort of "function" (a propositional function) that maps numbers into assertions about them; i.e. $\beta(\mathbf S\mathbf 0)$ is an assertion (true or false) about the number $1$, ans so on with $\beta(\mathbf S\mathbf S\mathbf 0)$, etc.

The **Fixed-Point Lemma** asserts that, for any such $\beta$ we can find a sentence $\sigma$ (in the first-order language of arithmetic) such that the "function" corresponding to $\beta$ maps the Gödel number of $\sigma$, i.e. the number $\sharp\sigma$, into the "assertion" $\sigma$ itself.